# How to make a child element inside a DIV take up the full size of the container

Tags: html, css

I have an input element and I want it to take up the full size of the parent DIV. How do I achieve this? I tried `width 100%`, yet it doesn't work. The problem I am facing is that the Parent has a blue background and the child has a yellow background. As a result, I can see some blue outline around the edges. How do I get rid of that.

I have a added a class for the child element. Something like this:

```
.input-editable { background-color: some-color; width: 100%; }
```

This element is wrapped in a div. That DIV has its background-color set that is visible on the edges. I don't want that to happen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like a CSS Reset will do you a little good.

Comment: @Zoltan Toth: I added some more comments.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your `input` a block element and it will work - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JgXrT/)

```
.div input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code: (http://jsfiddle.net/MUDey/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        *{padding:0;margin:0;}
        #parent { width: 75%; height: auto; background-color: Blue; }
        .input-editable {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <input type="text" class="input-editable" value="Show us your HTML" />

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And please, post your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is

```
display: block;
width: 100%;
```

That will make your input element span the whole width of the parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/pTQWM/

Note that if you have padding on your input element, you better use this as well:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```